# Swift testing non-scalar types

Tags: swift

I want to test my function that takes a string, a returns all the pairs of characters as an array s.t.

```
func pairsOfChars(_ s: String) -> [(Character,Character)] {
    let strArray = Array(s)
    var outputArray = [(Character,Character)]()
    for i in 0..<strArray.count - 1 {
        for j in i + 1..<strArray.count {
            outputArray.append( (strArray[i], strArray[j]) )
        }
    }
    return outputArray
}
```

So I want to create a suite of tests using XCTestCase. I usually use XCTestCase and XCTAssertEqual but these are only appropriate for C scalar types. This means that the following test case returns an error:

```
    class pairsTests: XCTestCase {
        func testNaive() {
            measure {
                XCTAssertEqual( pairsOfChars("abc") , [(Character("a"),Character("b")),(Character("a"),Character("c")),(Character("b"),Character("c")) ] )
            }
        }
    }
```

I could convert to a string, but I'm thinking there is a better solution.

**How can I test an output of an array of pairs of characters [(Character,Character)]**

Answer (score 1):

Your notion of a nonscalar is a total red herring. The problem is one of equatability.

> How can I test an output of an array of pairs of characters `[(Character,Character)]`

You can't, because there is no default notion of what it would mean to equate two such arrays. This is the old "tuples of Equatable are not Equatable" problem (https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1222) which still rears its head with arrays. The `==` operator works on tuples by a kind of magic, but they are still not formally Equatable.

You could define equatability of arrays of character pairs yourself:

```
typealias CharPair = (Character,Character)
func ==(lhs:[CharPair], rhs:[CharPair]) -> Bool {
    if lhs.count != rhs.count {
        return false
    }
    let zipped = zip(lhs,rhs)
    return zipped.allSatisfy{$0 == $1}
}
```

Alternatively, have your `pairsOfChars` return something that is more easily made equatable, such as an array of a struct for which Equatable is defined.

For example:

```
struct CharacterPair : Equatable {
    let c1:Character
    let c2:Character
    // in Swift 4.2 this next bit is not needed
    static func ==(lhs:CharacterPair, rhs:CharacterPair) -> Bool {
        return lhs.c1 == rhs.c1 && lhs.c2 == rhs.c2
    }
}

func pairsOfChars(_ s: String) -> [CharacterPair] {
    let strArray = Array(s)
    var outputArray = [CharacterPair]()
    for i in 0..<strArray.count - 1 {
        for j in i + 1..<strArray.count {
            outputArray.append(CharacterPair(c1:strArray[i],c2:strArray[j]))
        }
    }
    return outputArray
}
```

You would then rewrite the test to match:

```
XCTAssertEqual(
    pairsOfChars("abc"),
    [CharacterPair(c1:Character("a"),c2:Character("b")), 
         CharacterPair(c1:Character("a"),c2:Character("c")),
         CharacterPair(c1:Character("b"),c2:Character("c"))]
)
```

Comment: Hmm. In production I wouldn't want to return a specific type just to make testing easier (that's clearly not the right approach). A trivial test case would then be XCTAssertEqual(pairsOfChars("abc").map{ String($0.0) + String($0.1) }, ["ab", "ac", "bc"] )

Comment: I'm not completely with you on that "clearly". Writing for testability is part of the art.

Comment: Anyway if you do a google search on equatability of tuples and especially of arrays of tuples you'll see that this is all nothing new.

Comment: I added an implementation of equatability for an array of character pair tuples. But you can see that this is hardly a general solution, as it is defined only for this exact type of tuple, even though equatability ought to mean this for every type of tuple.